# Moling System.dll

Tags: tdd, moles, pex, pex-and-moles

I need to unit test a method that is using the `System.Net.WebClient` in the `System.dll`. I tried to Mole the `System.dll`, but when I tried to compile the project to add references to the `System.dll` mole, I got a bunch of errors like the following:

Error   2

> 'System.Net.Moles.SFileWebResponse.Dispose(bool)': no suitable method found to override [C:\DGALibrary\DGALib.IO.Tests\obj\x86\Debug\Moles\s\m.g.csproj]   C:\DGALibrary\DGALib.IO.Tests\m.g.cs    251374  33  DGALib.IO.Tests

Error   3

> 'System.Net.Moles.SFileWebResponse.SupportsHeaders': no suitable method found to override [C:\DGALibrary\DGALib.IO.Tests\obj\x86\Debug\Moles\s\m.g.csproj] C:\DGALibrary\DGALib.IO.Tests\m.g.cs    251575  30  DGALib.IO.Tests

Error   4

> 'System.Net.Moles.SHttpWebResponse.Dispose(bool)': no suitable method found to override [C:\DGALibrary\DGALib.IO.Tests\obj\x86\Debug\Moles\s\m.g.csproj]   C:\DGALibrary\DGALib.IO.Tests\m.g.cs    255264  33  DGALib.IO.Tests

Error   5

> 'System.Net.Moles.SHttpWebResponse.SupportsHeaders': no suitable method found to override [C:\DGALibrary\DGALib.IO.Tests\obj\x86\Debug\Moles\s\m.g.csproj] C:\DGALibrary\DGALib.IO.Tests\m.g.cs    255465  30  DGALib.IO.Tests

Error   6

> 'System.Net.Moles.SWebResponse.Dispose(bool)': no suitable method found to override [C:\DGALibrary\DGALib.IO.Tests\obj\x86\Debug\Moles\s\m.g.csproj]   C:\DGALibrary\DGALib.IO.Tests\m.g.cs    303123  33  DGALib.IO.Tests

Error   7

> 'System.Net.Moles.SWebResponse.SupportsHeaders': no suitable method found to override [C:\DGALibrary\DGALib.IO.Tests\obj\x86\Debug\Moles\s\m.g.csproj] C:\DGALibrary\DGALib.IO.Tests\m.g.cs    303324  30  DGALib.IO.Tests

Error   8

> 'System.Net.Moles.SFileWebResponse.Dispose(bool)': no suitable method found to override [C:\DGALibrary\DGALib.IO.Tests\obj\x86\Debug\Moles\s\m.g.csproj]   C:\DGALibrary\DGALib.IO.Tests\m.g.cs    251374  33  DGALib.IO.Tests

And finally

Error   28

> The command ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Moles\bin\moles.exe" @C:\DGALibrary\DGALib.IO.Tests\obj\x86\Debug\Moles\moles.args" exited with code -1002.   DGALib.IO.Tests

Are we not able to mole `system.dll`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
<Moles xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/moles/2010/">
  <Assembly Name="System" ExportedTypes="true" ReflectionOnly="true"/>  
</Moles>
```

Comment: yes, I think you are right. I was watching a vidoe on Pex, Moles and Code Contracts and they manually inserted the moles file with correct filtering

Comment: at least that actually helped me

Comment: I actually added the text below and it worked. It seems there are some types in they system.dll that can't be stubbed
    <Moles xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/moles/2010/">
 <Assembly Name="System" />
 <StubGeneration Disable="true"/>
</Moles>

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Pex/Moles so I can't provide you with an answer as to why the errors are occurring. However, so long as the errors aren't for types you actually need to Mole you can resolve your problem by editing the system.moles file to restrict the types to mole to just the ones you care about.