# What classes have methods which Moles can redirect?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mocking, moles, pex-and-moles

I've seen samples using Moles to redirect `DateTime.Now` but when I tried to redirect `System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.GetStream` I couldn't make the corresponding `MTcpClient` appear on Intellisense.

Is there a limited number of classes which methods Moles can redirect? Is there any step that I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's `System.Net.Sockets.Moles.MTcpClient`, don't forget the `Moles` namespace.

Second, there seems to be a quirk when mocking Core.dll: after adding the .moles file for this assembly the usual way (by right-clicking the reference in Solution Explorer) you need to modify it to look like this:

```
<Moles xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/moles/2010/">
  <Assembly Name="System" ExportedTypes="true" ReflectionOnly="true" />
</Moles>
```

or else you might get build errors as described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8144653/129073).